# choosing with no order but with repetition - how to think?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I will start with an example here:

assume we have 50 apples and 70 bananas to be divided between 10 people. How many ways can we do that ?

we count number of ways to distribute the apples between the 10 people, which is $59\choose50$

then we count the number of ways to distribute the bananas, which is $79\choose70$

and then the totalt is gives by using multiplication principle => $59\choose50$ * $79\choose70$

**Example 2**

Assume we have 4 boxes that contians red balls, green balls, blue balls and pink balls, how many ways can we choose 20 balls of these ? 
we get  $23\choose20$ ways.

So my question is how do i know when to count the number of ways for each of the types and then use multiplication principle to get the total ? and when to just combine everything like in example 2 ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: I have already read that, still i done have the answer for my question. Could tell you me why the 2 examples above are approached a bit differently? they are pretty much identical , what is the hint in the text that tells use multiplication principle and not solve like we did in example 2 ?

Comment: In the second question the colors of the selected balls do not really matter, while in the first question to be an apple or a banana makes a difference.

Comment: yeah after seeing the solution, i would agree that the colors does not matters. But just by reading the text, i am pretty much guessing which way to solve the problem, its like 50/50 chance. Or am i missreading the text ?

Comment: I disagree with  "colors don't matter". Suppose that instead of colors, we were dealing with types of candy, say, lollipops, hard candy, jelly candy and licorice, the answer would be the same ! I have answered with a different explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For greater clarity, we shall take up Example 2 first.

*Example 2*

To put it into the standard stars-and-bars mould, invert the problem to **putting** identical balls into distinct (colored) boxes, $\to \binom{23}3 or \binom{23}{20}$ according to your preference. This is a **single** use of stars-and-bars

*Example 1*

Here the case is different. You are using stars-and-bars **twice**, for distributing two **classes** of identical items (apples, bananas), to distinct people, so the multiplication principle enters in.